# What does 'y' in the output stand for in C?

Tags: c, string

I have a problem, I construct a string in a loop and the output of that string to stout displays the string and a character 'y' with two dots above it as the last character.

What is that?

I create the string in this function:

```
char get_string(char *buf, int ble, FILE *fp, char del)
{
    int i = 0;
    int c;
    char    result;

    memset(buf, 0, BUFLEN);

    do {

        c = fgetc(fp);

        if (c == del) {
            buf[i] = '\0';
            result = c;
            break;
        } else if(c == '\n') {
            buf[i] = '\0';
            result = '\n';
            break;
        } else {
            buf[i] = c;
            i++;
        }

    } while (c != EOF);

    return result;
}
```

and then use the buf and result as follows in another function:

```
char    pair[BUFLEN];
char    end;

do {

        end = get_string(pair, BUFLEN, fp, ';');
        printf("Result: %s\n",pair);

} while (pair != NULL);
```

The last iteration of the above Prints out "Result: y" I have no idea why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ÿ is the glyph for the character which (in Unicode and many ISO-8859-? encodings) has the ordinal value 0xFF. That value, also known in decimal as 255, is also used in some contexts as "the end-of-file character" (aka EOF) -- although there's no standard that defines *the character* as such (AFAIK), the value -1 is what does get returned in many languages (such as C) when you try to read more from a file that's exhausted ("at end of file").

In practice, therefore, an unexpected ÿ in your output often means that you are erroneously interpreting a byte that's intended to signify "end of something" (a byte encoded with all bits set to one) as if it was part of the text to display.

Comment: Small nitpick - it's the glyph for the Unicode codepoint `U+00FF`, which in UTF-8 corresponds to the byte `0xFF`.

Comment: @Jesse, in Unicode it can be written U+00FF (which has the ordinal value 255 in decimal, FF in hex, etc), in ISO-8859-1 (&c) of course it can't be written with a 'U' prefix (while 0xFF is still right;-), and this codepoint in UTF-8 is encoded as a TWO-byte sequence, 0xC3 0xBF, which has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: My bad, you're right that in UTF-8 it's a two-byte sequence. But I think the proper way to refer to the Unicode codepoint is `U+00FF`, whereas `0xFF` refers to the byte with all bits set (or simply the number 255). Of course, this is only from reading bits and pieces about Unicode; I'm not an expert, so I'm happy to be corrected. (The wikipedia page, for example, only refers to codepoints by U+stuff). I probably shouldn't have mentioned that UTF-8 bit without thinking for a second, though :)

Comment: -1 for misleading explanation (there is no EOF "character" in C, and it does not have the value 255 or any other; it's an out-of-band indicator value). The problem you failed to see is that the code has the usual beginner's mistake of expecting EOF be set after reading the last character.

Answer (score 9):

You're using a `do`-`while` loop, which means that you're executing the loop body before testing for `EOF`, so you end up putting `EOF` in your buffer as well. The `EOF` value of -1 gets translated into the character range where it corresponds to ÿ. I'd recommend you to just switch to a more usual `while` loop because it handles this condition more naturally.

Answer (score 2):

'y' with two dots over it is character 0xFF (in latin-1 - the default codepage for the console).

0xFF as a 8-bit signed value is -1.

Look for places where you're printing -1 as a char (or using -1 as a char and then printing it).

Answer (score 1):

When you "construct your string in a loop", do you remember to properly terminate it with a `'\0'`?

If the loop assigns characters to a character array, the last array item should be `'\0'`.

Ok, after seeing the code, you are terminating the string.

**EDIT**:

Looks like you are including the EOF character in your string. This is one case where the string is not terminated properly. You should check for an EOF in your if-else structure and handle it properly.

One other thing I noticed:

You are assigning an `int c` to a `char result` when returning from your function. The compiler should have warned you, that you are trying to put a larger data type into a smaller data type. Depending on what the purpose of the return value is, I would think about changing the return data type to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`-statement, which ends with an else putting the character into the buffer has two flaws:

1. It does not filter out the `EOF` special "character", which signifies the end of the stream
2. It does not check for buffer overrun by comparing `i` with the `BUFLEN` value.

The first problem is the cause of your ÿ character, when the stream ends, you add the `EOF` character to the buffer, then the loop terminates.

The fix is to put a clause into your `if-else` statement to filter that away, like this:

```
} else if (c != EOF) {
    buf[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

The second problem you need to decide how to handle before fixing, but it *should* be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not properly null-terminate your string. If reading from *fp* never returns "del" or "\n" and you reach EOF, there will be no null-terminator. You need to fix your code.